# Entity Framework Many To Many With Two Self Referencing Composite Keys

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

I have an entity that uses a composite key as the PK.  I want to add a collection of `QuestStage` to itself but when mapping the keys, Entity Framework tells me that the key was already used.  What is the best way to handle this scenario?  I need both keys to share `QuestID` since both `QuestStages` belong to a single `Quest`

**Entity - PK (QuestID, Stage)**

```
public class QuestStage
{
    public QuestStage
    {
        FollowUpQuestStages = new List<QuestStage>();
    }

    public int QuestID { get; set; }
    public int Stage { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<QuestStage> FollowUpQuestStages { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
public class QuestStageMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<QuestStage>
{
    public QuestStageMap()
    {
        // Non Problematic Mappings

        // Problematic Mapping
        HasMany(x => x.FollowUpQuestStages)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("FollowUpQuestStage");
                m.MapLeftKey("QuestID", "StageID");
                m.MapRightKey("QuestID", "FollowUpStageID");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: By your example I assume you are using the "code first" approach. Have you tried "database first" when doing this?

Comment: Yes I am using code first.  I have not tried database first but I could try it and see what it generates for me.

Comment: It would be my first try - mostly because SQL is a better friend of mine than EF. ;)

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I finally got it to work.  I did decide to change names up a bit but it's the same idea.

**Entity**

```
    public partial class QuestStageChain
    {
        public int QuestID { get; set; }
        public int StageID { get; set; }
        public int NextStageID { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestStage QuestStage { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestStage NextQuestStage { get; set; }
    }
```

**Mapping**

```
        this.HasRequired(t => t.QuestStage)
            .WithMany(t => t.QuestStageChains)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.QuestID, d.NextStageID })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.NextQuestStage)
            .WithMany(t => t.NextQuestStages)
            .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.QuestID, d.StageID })
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```